# CAS server and service tickets using SAML

Tags: cas, saml

Sorry for what might be a silly question, I couldn't find the answer.... When working with a CAS server, why is the format of the service ticket I receive different when I use saml ( samlValidate ).  When not using SAML, eg. serviceValidate, the ticket comes back in the form: ST-956-Lyg0BdLkgdrBO9W17bXS
When using SAML, it looks like 'AAFSsPYAkNKN6Mb0Q6Li8D8gawrtLPYezN1rpJ9JNZRSn1XM0kRgPJjj'
And more importantly, why the difference and what determines the format?  Is it configurable on the CAS server??

TIA

MPM

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 3 protocols to use with CAS are they CAS 1, CAS 2 and SAML. So all of them should generate a ticket but each one with your own implementation. In [this](http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol) link you can see in deep about these protocols.